# How to integrate FileReader in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I commented that I was reading the official documentation a lot, and I fully understand the concept and functioning of this. The problem is that it costs me a bit more to apply it in reality. So I started to practice and I came across something that puzzled me, I want to create a button that loads an image and shows the preview of it. However, this consists of some steps such as;

- verify that the image has been uploaded correctly
- create a fileReader
- update the status of my application (path, and name of the image)
- show the image

This would look like this:

```
onImageChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = event.target.files[0];

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                imageFile: file,
                imageName: file.name
            });
        }   
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
}
```

I tried to create an action and that the payload is image Name and imageFile but I do not know where to put the reader ...

this is my component currently:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ImageModalForm from "../../../Commons/components/ImageModalForm";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { loadImage } from "../../actions";

const faceImage = require("../../../../img/face5.gif");

class ThumbnailComp extends Component {
  onImageChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = event.target.files[0];

      reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
          imageFile: file,
          imageName: reader.result
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageModalForm
        imageFile={this.props.imageFile}
        imageName={this.props.imageName}
        onImageChange={this.onImageChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    image: state.image
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loadImage }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ThumbnailComp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Any correction is welcome ... Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just pass `reader.result` to redux action creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just pass result from FileReader to action creator?

```
onImageChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = event.target.files[0];

      reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.props.loadImage(reader.result)
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

// action creator
const loadImage = (result) => ({ type: LOAD_IMAGE, result })
```

side note - you can't pass events to redux as [SyntheticEvents gets nullified](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling).

However, if you want to make this outside of component you need to do it in action creator - don't do it in reducer as they need to be pure without any side-effects. You will also need some kind of middleware to do it - the simplest yet enough for this would be [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) - which allows you to return a function from your action creators:

```
onImageChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.props.loadImage(file)
    }
}

// action creator
const loadImage = file => dispatch => {
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_IMAGE_IN_REDUCER',
      image: reader.result
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}


// example reducer
const initialState = { image: null };
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_IMAGE_IN_REDUCER': 
      return { ...state, image: action.image }
    ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `dispatch` is undefined in the action creator.

Comment: @dbow you will need redux-thunk middlewarr

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem, I would do it that way. But I'm not sure...

action.js

```
function loadImage(event){
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){
   let file = event.target.files[0];
   let fileName = file.name
  }
  return {
   type: LOAD_IMAGE,
   payload: { imageFile: file, imageFileName: fileName }
 }
}
```

Comment: i think that, but i dont know where to put 'new FileReader' and 'reader.readDataAsURL(file)', etc

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way. I had to import `store` to use `dispatch` in the promise.

*action creator*

```
import store from '../store/index';

export const UPLOAD_FILE = 'UPLOAD_FILE';

export function uploadTextFile(file) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => { resolve(reader.result) };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }).then(result => store.dispatch({
        type: UPLOAD_FILE,
        payload: result}
    ));
}
```

*store*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

*component (partly code, redux binding)*

```
// ...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ uploadTextFile }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponentName);
```